# Exception while trying to return a rss feed in Nancy

Tags: c#, rss, nancy

I encountered a problem with my web app.
When I run it locally everything works great, I get a rss feed. But when I deploy my app to a remote machine. I get an error like this:

```
Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'UriFormatException'
Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm,cshtml,vbhtml
Locations inspected: views/Renderer/UriFormatException-pl,views/Renderer/UriFormatException,Renderer/UriFormatException-pl,Renderer/UriFormatException,views/UriFormatException-pl,views/UriFormatException,UriFormatException-pl,UriFormatException
Root path: C:\WebAppPath
If you were expecting raw data back, make sure you set the 'Accept'-header of the request to correct format, for example 'application/json'
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewFactory.GetRenderedView(String viewName, Object model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , DefaultViewFactory , Object , Object , ViewLocationContext )
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewFactory.RenderView(String viewName, Object model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IViewFactory , String , Object , ViewLocationContext )
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.ViewProcessor.Process(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, Object model, NancyContext context)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IResponseProcessor , String , Object , NancyContext )
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.DefaultResponseNegotiator.NegotiateResponse(IEnumerable`1 compatibleHeaders, NegotiationContext negotiationContext, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.DefaultResponseNegotiator.CreateResponse(IList`1 compatibleHeaders, NegotiationContext negotiationContext, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.DefaultResponseNegotiator.NegotiateResponse(Object routeResult, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
```

And here is a part of my code which is responsible for generating a rss feed..

```
Get["GetFeed"] = _ => 
{
    var feed = _feedProvider.GetFeed();
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='format.xsl'");
        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed).WriteTo(xmlWriter);
    }

    var res = (Response) sw.ToString();
    res.ContentType = "text/xml";
    return res;
}
```

Also I have another actions which returns simple json and they works fine on localmachine and also on remote. I have no idea, why this particular code which returns something different than json/html/plain text doesn't run on a remote machine.

If it depends I use .net 4.5 and Nancy 1.4.2

## Edit I add a log4net to check logs for more sophisticated error description.

In logs I have a following error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

And a only portion of code which uses a Uri is a _feedProvider.GetFeed() function.

```
public SyndicationFeed Get()
{
    var alternateLink = new Uri(urlFromConfig);
    var items = GetItems();
    return new SyndicationFeed("Title", "", alternateLink, items)
    {
        Copyright = new TextSyndicationContent(""),
        Language = "pl-PL",
        ImageUrl = new Uri(anotherUrlFromConfig)
    };
}
```

Comment: `I encourage a problem with my web app.` do you mean you `encountered ?` also if it works on your local machine and does not work on the remote machine.. this is one of those things that you will have to check to see the following, is the .net framework on the target machine installed, do you have all the .dll's and 3rd party .dll's deployed to the target machine..? for the `Nancy 1.4.2 dll` make sure that when you click on that Dll in the References node on your local machine, that you have `CopyLocal=` set to `True` make sure that you have same virtual paths setup on target that you locally

Comment: @MethodMan yes I mean encountered, sorry for that. I check everything, dlls, version of dlls etc. I add a log4net configuration to a project and in logs i found out that the problem is with creating a Uri object... So I investigating it right now. But the default stacktrace from a Nancy is not so helpful..

Comment: what is the issue with the URI..? you do not show that particular code and or portion in regards to that issue.. can you edit your question and post that as well..?

Comment: "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." So I suppose that a string provided to a Uri ctor is without http:// prefix. Yes of course I could provide 'this' portion of code which fails.

Comment: Yup It's a problem with an variable passed to a Uri constructor. It works fine right now. I will edit my question and add an answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have a different values for any env in my app.config. So on local machine everything works fine. But on a remote machine I get errors because

> urlFromConfig
>
> anotherUrlFromConfig

are set to a urls without a

> http://

prefix, so when I add it everything starts to work fine.